# PKIX path building failed / javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error in Spring Boot App Deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, soap

I have a Spring Boot application that communicates with a SOAP Web Service over HTTPS, using NTLM authentication. To establish a secure connection, the web service requires certificates for validation. To accommodate this, I've added all three necessary certificates into a truststore.

Below is how I've configured the truststore in my Spring Boot application:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

I'm encountering an SSLHandshakeException issue when deploying my Spring Boot application to a Tomcat server. The application works fine in the local development environment, but when deployed to Tomcat, it throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.example.ePisarnicaWebService.SOAP.SoapClient.createCaseAndAct(SoapClient.java:96) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.example.ePisarnicaWebService.SOAP.SoapController.createCaseAndAct(SoapController.java:50) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.79]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:376) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:319) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1296) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:121) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[na:na]
        ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
        ... 93 common frames omitted
```

Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this SSLHandshakeException specifically when deploying a Spring Boot application on a Tomcat server? Is there something I might be missing in the configuration or any additional steps to troubleshoot this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!